# "I know it" vs. "I know this"

Tags: meaning, pronouns

What is the difference between these two phrases: "I know it" and "I know this"? One explanation I found is that "it" means what you perceive and "this" is more abstract. Is it so?

Comment: In this context, "Is this so?" seems more natural to my (American) ear than "Is it so?".

Comment: I don't think the explanation you found is correct, but I also can't figure out the difference myself.

Comment: It would've been more helpful with context

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to say with any certainty what the nuanced differences might be.  Here are some plausible uses:

**She's taking money from the till, I know it! There should be more money here. We've had a busy day.**

or:

**I know this (or This I know): when you're serious about going to medical school, you don't party every weekend.**

Answer (score 0):

For *I know it*, this is used more often in the past tense:

> I **knew it**! He seemed strange from the beginning.

It is a confirmation of some suspicion or idea.

In the present tense it is pretty literal.

For I *know this*:

> I can't believe that I could not repair the car. **I know** (how to do) **this**.

meaning you know how to repair the car but for some reason you couldn't. In this case it is an expectation of ability.